# how to group an array based on a specific function?

Tags: javascript, frontend

Here, I am new to JavaScript. I am solving questions; however, I am having a problem understanding chaining more than one method together. I have been trying to understand this solution, but it took me a lot of time, and I still don't get it.

I understand that I will input the array that I needed to change according to the specific function, which I opted. I understand all of methods functions, but I don't understand their syntax here, so can someone please explain each step to me ?

```
const group_By = (arr, fn) =>
  arr.map(typeof fn === 'function' ? fn : val => val[fn]).reduce((acc, val, i) => {
    acc[val] = (acc[val] || []).concat(arr[i]);
    return acc;
  }, {});
```

Comment: If you are learning, try to find what that is in a documentation about JavaScript. I like to use [MDN's JavaScript guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide). There is also a [JavaScript tutorial for beginners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics) if you like. Understanding JS piece by piece doesn't help as much as knowing how to look into the documentation.

Comment: This is really helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In as few words as possible.

Firstly they compute a ternary expression, here they are checking if the input is a function, if it is they pass it as is, otherwise they create an anonymous function that tries to access the given property. The arrow function after the colon can seem a little confusing but it's still just a function. It takes one argument called `val`, and returns property which key is inside the fn variable.

```
typeof fn === 'function' ? fn : val => val[fn]
```

The next step is to create a new array with new values for each of the elements. Output of this step is just a list of values to group elements on.
For instance calling it on array `["a", "bb"]` with a `fn='length'` would return `[1,2]`

```
arr.map(typeof fn === 'function' ? fn : val => val[fn])
```

Then they call the `.reduce` function on the output array. The purpose of the reduce function is to create a single value out of all the elements slowly iterating over it. You can tell that the last step returns accumulator value back, and that it is passed as a first argument to the function called on the next element. The empty object at the end is just an initial value of the accumulator.

```
.reduce((acc, val, i) => {
  ...
  return acc;
}, {});
```

And finally for the step that does the accumulation. Here firstly the `val` from the result of the map, is used to access property of the newly created object. If the value does not exist it replaced with an empty array `|| []`. That has the element of the initial array at the same index concatenated onto it. If there were some elements it just adds new ones to it and reassigns the value.

```
acc[val] = (acc[val] || []).concat(arr[i]);
```

Comment: I don't know really how to thank you. This helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, what I understood from your query is that you are trying to chain multiple functions together.

```
function Chained() {
  // this reference.
  const _this_ = this

  this.Function1 = () => // do something and return _this_
  this.Function2 = () => // do something here and return _this_
}
```

Above you can see that chain is a simple object which returns "this" as context. and on context, we already have Function1 and Function2. so due to this following will be valid.

```
const _ExecuteChained = new Chained()
// Now you can run _ExecuteChained.Function1().Function2() and so on.
```

Now coming to your code.

```
const group_By = (arr, fn) =>
arr.map(typeof fn === 'function' ? fn : val => val[fn]).reduce((acc, val, 
i) => {
 acc[val] = (acc[val] || []).concat(arr[i]);
 return acc;
}, {});
```

Here you are just running a loop on `arr` and validating if the second param is a function or not if function then return it as is (Since you are using a `map` it will be stored at the given index. else just get the value of the function at the given key and return it.

## Reduce.

in Reduce you are trying to accumulate a given value with (contact or merge or extend)  value at a given index of `arr` in this case function.